# HTML5 Audio - Detecting a click on iPad/iPhone, iOS 7

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, ios7, html5-audio

I cannot get an audio tag to detect a click when it is running in iOS 7 (haven't tried earlier versions of the OS).

It works fine in a browser. Here is my code:

```
    <audio id="myAudioPlayer" controls>
    <source src="audio/myTrack.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="audio/myTrack.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="audio/myTrack.acc" type="audio/acc">
    Your browser does not support the audio tag. </audio>
```

Jquery:

```
 $("#myAudioPlayer").mouseup(function(){

    // DO STUFF                      

  });
```

iOS 7 uses it's own styling for the HTML5 player so I am wondering if this is the issue? I can use the player controls as normal, but my custom functions do not work.

Comment: After doing some research into this, it looks like touch events are very buggy with HTML5 and iOS. Anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a fix for this so I ended up building a custom player with SoundManager2.

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

This allowed more control over my play/pause buttons and worked on iOS devices.